# "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider" with IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider

Tags: .net, db2, dataprovider, enterprise-library-5

I'm getting this error on our UAT server after deploying an application. It works fine on other environments including DEV & QA servers.

- UAT Server is windows 2008 R2 with SP2 64bit, .NET 4.0 and IBM .Net Data Provider
- DEV & QA boxes have windows 2003 with SP2 32bit, .NET 4.0 and IBM .Net Data Provider

We use Enterprise Library 5.0. Here is the configuration in web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseServer" connectionString="Server=XXX;Database=XXXX;UID=XXXX;PWD=XXXX;" providerName="IBM.Data.DB2" />
</connectionStrings>

<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="DatabaseServer"/>

<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
         <remove invariant="IBM.Data.DB2"></remove>
         <add name="IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2" description="IBM DB2 Data Provider for .NET Framework 2.0" type="IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

It works fine and connects to the database on 32-bit servers. I had developed a Windows application to test the database connection on 64-bit servers and included all the configuration in app.config. That also works perfectly, however when accessing the website through IIS, it throws this error:

> Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Which version is client Access at? (V5R4, V7R1, etc).  IBM didn't exactly honor the "avoid dll hell" issue with their provider, and the version matters: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas1ed6f6dcdf7015272862574470072d30f

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Client Access you're using, the IBM.DB2.iSeries component may or may not work.  We're at V5R4 for the time being, while we scramble to fix all the code we had that broke when the 6.1 version came out. The V5R4 version won't work at all on 64-bit.  I'm not sure about the more recent versions.

One option you have is to set your project to compile targeting x86, rather than X64, Itanium, or Any CPU.